# List of fallback sites to get ip address

Tags: ip-address

My ISP changes the IP address of my server (which is running at home, while I'm at campus) quite frequently (every few months), so I decided to write a script to periodically check when it changes and then send me an email when it does, because I have no way to see what it is if I can no longer access it. I am currently using ip.jsontest.com to get my public ip, but I cannot guarantee that that site will always be working, so I would like to have a few fallback sites that can be used if this site fails.

Does anybody have a list that they can give me? I'd prefer sites that return simple json or plain text so that I don't have to parse a massive HTML file.

Comment: Why not use dyndns to do this?

Comment: I don't want to pay for it. I'm already paying for the domain and I got a pretty good deal. DynDns costs $35 a year if you want to use an external domain.

Comment: Wow seriously? I've always known it to be free :s Oh bummer.

Comment: It used to be. Then it got acquired by someone I think. Either way, it isn't anymore